# Set previous and next page on my jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to add previous and next page link on my jsp. To be clear to you, see this picture

[image]

I load 4 books on my container div, and there are five in database, so when user click on 'next page' it need to load that fifth book. It need to work with 10,20, or more books, so I need solution that will work 100%.

I will appreciate if a solution is not too comlicated. :) Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english. And one more thing, I work with `Java EE` tehnology, and using `mvc model`.

Comment: J2ee is vast & lots of J2ee framework build on mvc model. Could u plz tell us the exact technologies u have used in ur project?

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly: Wow, are you **still** using J2EE even though it died nearly a decade ago?

Comment: @ BalusC how it is related with India? U surely have some problem with India, but that is not my business and it should not be the business of any SO users.

Comment: @ BalusC comment can be edited, we all know that. Be a **MAN**.